# What will happen if I call startActivityForResult() recursively?

Tags: android

I intend to show four welcome screens to the user that only appear once for new users. To do so, I save a flag in the Preferences at start up and check its value to determine if the user is new or not. If not, then the welcome screens do not appear:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String welcomePref = "oldUser";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean welcome = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomePref, false);

    if (!welcome) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, welcomeScreenOne.class);
        startActivity(intent); //start the first welcome screen

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomePref, true); //not a new user anymore
        editor.commit(); 
    }

}
```

The welcomeScreenOne activity starts the second welcome screen and so on. 
As you may have noticed, the error in this code is that if the user views the first welcome screen, the pref is set to true and so if he exits the application before looking at the other welcome screen (2, 3 and 4) then returning to the app will not display the remaining screens.

To solve this I thought of using `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` inside each welcome screen activity so that the 4th returns to the 3rd, which returns to the 2nd which returns to the 1st welcome screen, then setting the pref to `true`. Is this bad coding practice?

My second solution is calling the 1st screen from the main, returning then calling the 2nd, returning then calling the 3rd and so on.

Maybe there is a way I do not know of, please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this bad coding practice?

IMHO, yes.

> Maybe there is a way I do not know of, please advise?

Have one activity, not four.

Use something else inside this one activity for your sequence of welcome screens, such as:

- Four fragments, showing one at a time
- Four views, showing one at a time
- An existing library for such welcome screens, such as [these wizards](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/131) or [these "showcase views"](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for you to add a splashActivity to your app? if so, you can check on that activity if the user is new or not, and if is new, show the welcome screen and if not, send it to your mainActivity (or the activity you need).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the activity mode you are launching the activity if you will use launch mode Single Instance than the same activity will get reopened again and again ,if the default mode will be there every time a new instance will be created and there will be activities piled up in the stack which can create unknown results